# Secure boot and bios boot capible portable recovery drive using grub boot loader

Tags: bios, uefi, grub2, hard-drive-recovery

I am needing to make a portable recovery flash drive that is both secure uefi and legacy bios boot capable.  I have been using grub4win on the previous versions but now that I have to include uefi based systems with legacy turned off I was hoping to use grub2 on the system to boot to either uefi settings or a legacy boot loader depending on what kind of bios setting was turned on in the pc rather than having multiple flash drives per tech.

If there is another boot loader method that works like grub does that would also work.  I have a couple floppy images that I load from the grub menu plus dell diags and lenovo maintenance utilities. I can get efi versions of the floppy's but would still need the legacy version bookable as well. most of the boot options are loading .img files in to ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win10pese is able to do a dual boot flash drive.  after you make a working iso to your liking  then select the copy to usb option. one of the settings makes it uefi and bios.  if you have multiple grub options for bios you will have to make appropriate changes for the uefi side with comparable uefi based tools.

for example lenovo diagnostics disk.  if it comes with a efi file you would need to add that efi file to the boot folder and edit the grub menu to include it.